# Attempt to invoke virtual method in React-Native

Tags: react-native

When i run my react native code it gives error and says:

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstance com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.getCatalystInstance()' on a null object reference**

[image]

but in case when I run my code the second time it does not show this  type of error and code runs successfully. what is the reason behind this error? Please suggest any answer.

and my App.js files here..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Image, Platform, Animated } from 'react-native';
const Sliding_Drawer_Width = 300;
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor()
  {
      super();
      this.Animation = new Animated.Value(0);
      this.Sliding_Drawer_Toggle = true;
  }
 ShowSlidingDrawer = () =>
  {
      if( this.Sliding_Drawer_Toggle === true )
      {
              Animated.timing(
                  this.Animation,
                  {
                      toValue: 1,
                      duration: 500
                  }
              ).start(() =>
              {
                  this.Sliding_Drawer_Toggle = false;
              });                 
      }
      else
      {
              Animated.timing(
                  this.Animation,
                  {
                      toValue: 0,
                      duration: 500
                  }
              ).start(() =>
              {
                  this.Sliding_Drawer_Toggle = true;
              });
      }
  }

  render() {
    const Animation_Interpolate = this.Animation.interpolate(
      {
          inputRange: [ 0, 1 ],
          outputRange: [ -(Sliding_Drawer_Width - 32), 0 ]
      });

    return (

          <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
              <Text style = {styles.TextStyle}> Components Which You Want To Show in App, Place Them Here. </Text>
                <Animated.View style = {[ styles.Root_Sliding_Drawer_Container, { transform: [{ translateX: Animation_Interpolate }]}]}>
                    <View style = { styles.Main_Sliding_Drawer_Container }>
                        <Text style = { styles.TextStyle } > Put All Your Components Here Which You Want To Show Inside Sliding Drawer. </Text>  
                    </View> 
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress = { this.ShowSlidingDrawer } style = {{ padding: 1 }}>
                        <Image source = {{ uri : 'https://reactnativecode.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Arrow_Icon.png' }} style = {{resizeMode: 'contain', width: 30, height: 30 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Animated.View>                
          </View>

    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create(
  {
      MainContainer:
      {
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
      },

      Root_Sliding_Drawer_Container:
      {
          position: 'absolute',
          flexDirection: 'row',
          left: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          top: (Platform.OS == 'ios') ? 20 : 0,
          width: Sliding_Drawer_Width,
      },

      Main_Sliding_Drawer_Container:
      {
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: '#FFC107',
          paddingHorizontal: 10,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center'
      },

      TextStyle: {

          fontSize: 25,
          padding: 10, 
          textAlign: 'center',
          color: '#FF5722'
      }

  });
```